# Store run configuration with project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm programming in NetBeans however i like to get used to Eclipse as well. I have a Maven project what i've developed in NetBeans and after importing it compiles fine in Eclipse. I'm using the Run or Debug feature of NetBeans a lot, and it's very comfortable that the run configuration gets stored with the project so i can actually commit it into version control and others can use it as well. Say i have a Java application project which has a main class. To run this, i need to define the correct class path for the exec goal (actually NetBeans automatically does this for me when creating the new project).

In Eclipse i have to define Run configurations which as far as i know gets stored in the workspace but not in the project. Is there any similar feature in Eclipse what i'm looking for?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes - open "Run" then "Run Configurations...", and select your configuration.  Click on the last tab, "Common".  Under "Save As", choose "Shared File" instead of "Local File".

[image]

This dialog is a little confusing.  The line next to "Shared File" can only be a path, not a file name - and it defaults to the root path of the current project.  Once you hit "Apply", a file named the [Run Configuration Name] + ".launch" is created within that folder.  So in my above example, this results in a "`/JavaTest/JavaTest.launch`" file.  This is something that can be comitted to version control.

Comment: A restart of  Eclipse is needed.

Comment: @androidyue - no restart of Eclipse is required in my experience.  If you still believe this to be the case, please elaborate on what doesn't work without a restart...