# JAVA - VM Arguments is not saving when exporting to zip/archive

Tags: java, jvm-arguments, splash-screen

Im using eclipse :D

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwUEI.png)

everytime i import it to other computer, the arguments disappear T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Launch Configuration in Eclipse is used when you run the code from within Eclipse. You can save a Launch Config, see here:
[Store run configuration with project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625060/store-run-configuration-with-project-in-eclipse)

I think what you're looking for though is a way to be able to bundle these vm args for an executable jar? The easy way to do this would be to ship a .cmd/.bat/.sh script with your jar that calls your jar with -jar and sets the args from the commandline.