# Eclipse cdt Egit commit run configuration

Tags: eclipse-cdt, egit

A short questions. Is there any possibility to commit the run configurations (example the arguments) I have in my eclipse to avoid any time that I use a different  pc or delete workspace to rewrite again all run configurations?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store run configuration with project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625060/store-run-configuration-with-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

You can save a launch configuration in your project.

1. Open Launch Configuration from *Debug...* or *Run...* menu item in the *Run* menu.
2. Select your launch configuration
3. In the *Common* tab, choose *Save as* a *Shared file:*. This will save a *.launch* file in the specified location.

Here is a screenshot to help:

[image: screenshot]