# Howto import Eclipse gradle projects and run / launch configurations from command line

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am provisioning a dev environment to a VM using Vagrant and Chef. It works great for provisioning Eclipse and all needed plugins  but leaves the developer the tasks of importing the Gradle project, their run configurations as well as Jboss Server run configuration. Is there a way to import the gradle projects and the run configurations using the command line? If so, these steps could be automated as part of creating the VM. TIA for your help.

Answer (score 1):

- run configuration: if you store them in the project folder, they are picked up by eclipse automatically. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8625088/1861362
- eclipse project: you can generate eclipse files using the gradle eclipse plugin, yet I'm not aware of any means to have them automatically imported in eclipse..