# Import Maven (or Gradle) project to Eclipse in command line

Tags: eclipse, m2e

I would to prepare virtual machine with Eclipse. I would like the Eclipse has pre-imported my Maven project. 
Is is possible to execute some script which imports the project to the eclipse, in similar way I can [pre-install plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36827764/2365727)?

I'm not interested in `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. I want import with the same process like clicking mouse

PS. Similar question for [Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39457684/2365727).

Answer (score -1):

You can add the Eclipse workspace which has your project imported to the vm.

Comment: As everybody knows, Earth lays on big turtle. But why big turtle does not fall? It is simple: there is another big turtle beneath :) Of course it is solution, but I would like to have continous VM delivery with Eclipse with imported project. And I would like make sure fresh project is imported to workspace, not project from past

Answer (score -2):

You may want to begin with converting your MVN project to a gradle one. Here is [how](https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/)

Once your build.gradle is created, open it and add this line:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

Go back to the command prompt and run gradle eclipse

Now the build creates a project file which your Eclipse IDE acan import and work on it as if it were originally created in Eclipse.

For more detail on configuring the Eclipse Plugin, see this [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html)

Note that the assumption here is that you have ann your PATHS set correctly.

Comment: I'm not Gradle expert, but I'm afraid your solution is effectively equal to `mvn eclipse:eclipse` - both converts M/G project to Eclipse project. mvn eclipse:eclipse is outdated by m2e, I feel that `apply plugin: 'eclipse' ` is outdated by Eclipse Buildship plugin

Comment: Thanks. Any sources that can link me to details on why and when it is getting outdated? I thought Buildship had no such plans for eclipse plugin

Comment: I think you can find much better sources that my trivial comment, but `gradle eclipse` creates Eclipse Java project. Comparing, importing through Buildship creates Gradle project.

Comment: Hmm. Eclipse gradle integration AFAIk is not dying anytime soon. No release notes of gradle says so. Maven also has no such plans if I skim thru their website.
You can do nothing additionlal (beyond what you can with a text editor and command prompt) with a pure gradle project, in eclipse. You will need to integrate the project through the plugins.

Go ahead with what you need and are most comfortable with. That is the first and final determinant.