# Specify Eclipse CDT Default Launch Config

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, launch

**PAIN POINT:**

Using Eclipse CDT - the launch configs I need are rather complex (little settings that are non-default values and other misc things) too many little things to remember, and easy to skip then stuff does not work.  I want to be able to semi-automate this process in project makefiles.

**Background:**

I have multiple projects, not stored in the workspace (my users "import the project"). In some cases projects are some what generated (they are external makefile projects.

**Requirement:** Specifically depending on what build configuration is required the launch config needs to change/tweak, the external Makefile can do that, or I can create one launch file for each config.  Or I can pre-populate them when I create the project

[example is normal development, debug/release but with unit-test variations]

The user might tweak the settings of course and want to save them.

**Requirement:** So that the launch files "travel with the project" - I want to check the into GIT, thus I want the .launch files kept in the same directory as the .project and .cproject files - as described here (thus they can be checked in and things are "self contained)

[Store run configuration with project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625060/store-run-configuration-with-project-in-eclipse)

**PROBLEMS and QUESTIONS**

1) Given existing launch configurations files (.launch files) in the ".project" directory, how can I browse/select from the list of existing ones that Eclipse does seem to previously know about.

{Example: Create a launch config called "FOO", copy this to "BAR", edit the BAR config file, replacing internal occurrences of FOO with BAR)

The BROWSE button in the "common" tab lets me select a directory to save but does not allow me to select an existing file

2) How can I tell eclipse File (*X*) is the default launch configuration for this project, or config(X) uses file(A) and config(Y) uses file (B)

3) Is there a way within the ".project" or ".config" or ".cproject" files to specify where to look for launch configurations, where to offer them?

4) Sure would be nice to have a file (or place in the .project, or .cproject) file that says: Launch configs for this project are in this directory - offer the user a list based on the files present in that directory

**bottom line:**

I'm sort of stuck - I can create launch files "correctly" with all required settings but I seem to have no means to tell Eclipse to use select/use them.

No amount of automation here seems to work, and I end up having to go back to manually creating and humanly forgetting settings in the project files.

**Places I've looked:**

Sort of the issue but not exactly

https://superuser.com/questions/521537/remove-launch-from-run-debug-drop-down-in-eclipse

Below - ARM describes the IMPORT process, but in my case all ".launch" files are grayed out and not selectable I don't know why and that is a different problem

I'd like to not make this a multi-step process - also see above about removing stale launch configs - you end up with too many launch configs in the history.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0446h/CJADBBIA.html

There are numerous other places but all seem to be "click here" or "use this menu item" and not addressing the external file issue.

Comment: 1 and 2) As far as I know, the launch configuration file name must always be the name actual launch configuration name (plus extension). There seems to be no possibility to export to arbitrary files. What I do here for numerous litte tweaks is creating `String Substitution Variables` (Window>Preferences>Run/Debug>String Substitution) and make the launch configurations and makefiles react on them (by setting environment variables to string substitution variable values) and using the environment variables in the makefiles.

Comment: This is why I hate eclipse - its these little usablity things that just make it fustrating as hell.  But marketing and business people say FREE FREE FREE and they don't use the f-ing tool

Comment: I wonder whether you will really find a commercial IDE that supports very exotic software development project setups out of the box...?